# True way for array months

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new in R.
I've data about about deep sea species and my sampling from July 2016 to July 2017.
I want take histogram by month with using ggplot.
ggplot create histogram by monthly but sort the months alphabetically.
How can I create a histogram start from July 2016 ?
Thank you.

#### My code:

```
ggplot(af, aes(x=cl)) +\
geom_histogram(binwidth=2, color="red") +\
facet_wrap(~date, ncol=2, nrow=7) +\
scale_x_continuous(name="Length Class (mm)") +\
scale_y_continuous(name ="Number of Specimens")
```

- af: Species which is interested in study
- cl: Carapace length

structure(list(date = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("july 2016", "aug 2016 ",
"sept 2016", "oct 2016", "nov 2016", "dec 2016", "jan 2017",
"feb 2017", "march 2017", "apr 2017", "may 2017", "june 2017",
"july 2017"), class = "factor"), cl = c(38.33, 32.47, 33.52,
38.33, 34.84, 34.66, 31.67, 47.87, 36.46, 52, 41, 40.41, 32.71,
35.5, 36.56)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: If possible, please share a sample of your data - this will help people answering your question. A guess is: your dates are coded as characters not in date format.

Comment: My data is like that

date                        cl
Apr 2017                23.16
Apr 2017                32.13
Sept 2016              27.55
nov 2016                55.11
July 2016               43.83
Feb 2017                18.13
June 2017              22.45
July 2017               42.11

My dataset has contain totaly 13 month (From july 2016 to july 2017) and approximately 5000 specimens.

Comment: @CoşkunMenderesAydın you should add a sample of your data in your question (not in comments), so it'd easier to us to help you out.

Comment: Sorry that i don't know how can i add my data to here.
If you say i can add it rapidly.

Comment: Use `dput(head(df,15))` to add data to your question. Click edit above.